# Latching group in xmodmap / core protocol mappings (XChangeKeyboardMapping())

Tags: x11, xmodmap

This question should probably go to retrocomputing since people should use XKB, but I am really curious how did they *latch* group switching with xmodmap / `XChangeKeyboardMapping()`.

I read xmodmap man and X11 lib documentation, and it seems that to have, say, English and Russian keyboard layout you need to map keysyms to some keycode 
(like `[code_for_letter_l] --> XK_l XK_L XK_Cyrillic_de XK_Cyrillic_DE`) and then map some keycode to MODE_SWITCH.

Pressing this code along with L gives russian letter "Д".

But how can I latch it? 
There is Lock modifier, but it only could be used with XK_Caps_Lock keysym (and ShiftLock which I do not understand).

Adding lock to MODE_SWITCH has no affect.

With linux console keymap I can add group to, say, AltGr and then add some keycode to AltGr_Lock to make it latch. And it works. But how do I do it in X?

I checked several modmaps for cyrillic and other non-latin layouts (ancient distros have a lot of them) and in all cases people either used capslock for it or did not have lock/latch at all.

So, I came to idea that is was not possible to switch layout with keys like "CTRL+Shift" before XKB (before 1996?), but is sounds ridiculous.
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is called *lock* becase *latch* means key will only affect next key.

There is **no** way to lock group in Core protocol but XKB extensions adds some keys according to *ISO/IEC 9995*.

XKB, Appendix C. New KeySyms: `ISO NEXT GROUP`
`keysymdefs.h`

`#define XK_ISO_Next_Group                0xfe08`

So, I added `keycode 133 = ISO_Next_Group_Lock` to `~/.xmodmap` and not Win key switches my groups